# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getValue' of undefined at onEdit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

```
function onEdit(e){
e.range.getValue()

}
```

I am just trying to run a simple `onEdit` code in Google Sheets, but the trigger execution log keep showing:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getValue' of undefined at onEdit(Code:4:17)

[image: log]

Comment: Are you sure you are telling everything that's going on in your script? `onEdit` should have an event object constructed with `range` property then. Please, log what `e` event object looks like in your case and update the post

Comment: Are you trying to run this from the script editor without supplying the event object

Comment: @Cooper - doesn't seem like they do - Stackdriver shows "Trigger" and "Simple Trigger" both failing, which wouldn't be the case if run from the editor as far as I recall [besides, shouldn't that be "cannot read property 'range' of undefined" then ?]. Although (re:answer) that's a cool way of emulating the event object for debugging, I must say

Answer (score 1):

Try running it this way:

Run test_onxxxEdit();

```
function test_onxxxEdit() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg=ss.getRange(?);
  const v=rg.getValue();
  onxxxEdit({source:ss,range:rg,value:v});
}

function onxxxEdit(e){
  e.range.getValue()

}
```